# App doesn't install on iPhone, but works on simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, build, ios-simulator

I've made a small app. I've always tested it in simulator and everything works just fine.

Today i've tried to instal it on my device and it doesn't seems to work.
I use XCode 4. When i hit the "Run" button a message appears that tells me that build succeeded, but right after that the app stops (just like hitting Command+'.' while running a normal app). Nothing is installed on iPhone.

Regards,
George

Comment: Do you have errors in your error log?

Comment: Unplugging and replugging the device usually works for me.
Also try: clean build, restarting xcode, restarting your mac.

Comment: Does the console say anything? Try disconnecting and reconnecting the device, then restarting Xcode, then restarting the device, and then restarting the computer.

Comment: There is nothing in console, no error log. I've tried with iPod and iPad and still no result. I've tried to clean, restart xcode, restart mac.

Comment: This behavior doesn't happen with any of my other projects.

Comment: Do you have a valid provisioning profile for the AppID, developer and device where you are trying to run the project?

Comment: Yes, i've tested that provisioning profile on another app and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Is your iOS device old?  I had the same issue on iPhone3G.  The issue was because XCode4 defaults to armv7, but 3G has to be armv6.  Check out someone who solved it here: [3G iPhone Device "finished running" but app won't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127343/3g-iphone-device-finished-running-but-app-wont-load)