# 3G iPhone Device "finished running" but app won't load

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-3gs, armv6

I'm trying to run an app on a 3G device. Xcode says that the app has "Finished running on the iPhone" but the app will not deploy. I think I have the architectures configured correctly (see image below)

[image]

[image]

any help would be great,

thanks

Comment: Check your deployment target if it has at least 4.2.1 (Which is the latest version supported by the iPhone 3G)

Comment: yes. the deployment target is set to 4.2. I've added a screenshot

Comment: "app will not deploy" does it install and not launch or not even install?

Comment: doesn't install on the device. It goes from Build Succeeded to "Finished running appName on iPhone" (the message in the Xcode toolbar)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured this out finally. In the Info.plist there's a "Required device capabilities" setting that was set to armv7. I was aware of the armv6 and armv7 requirements in the target build settings for the 3G model but not in the plist. here's a screenshot. hope it helps anyone else stuck with something similar:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks fine. I’ve seen this before; removing the device from the Organizer (selecting it in the list on the left of the “Devices” tab and clicking the “Remove” button at the bottom of the main panel), restarting Xcode, and connecting it again seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried that (3 times) still the same thing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the architecture in the target properties was set to Standard (armv7). I had to add the armv6 architecture and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Check "Required device capabilities" in settings.
I had problem with accelerometr set to OFF.
When I had remove this line, everything start working.

Same problem on 3G (iOS4) and 4GS (iOS5)

Answer (score 1):

Each .xib file and core data model also has a deployment property. It's in the identity inspector. Changing it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have it setup like this in the target build settings, not just the project build settings.

Comment: yes, those are the settings from the target build. the deployment target is 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the device usually fixes this one for me.

Comment: I've restarted and even restored the device, but still the same thing. Just the message "Finished running myApp on myDevice". I'll try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Under Build Settings at the top, you'll not a selection named 'Levels'. If you select this you may find that the Architecture and/or your Code Signing Identity is out of step with the settings that were showing under the 'Combined' setting. I had a case where an App was building successfully and simply not deploying on the phone. When I select "Levels" the values under my App target for these Build settings was incorrect. Once I set them here it deployed to the device fine.

Hope that helps.